# gitolite setup on Mac => git-upload-pack: command not found

Tags: git, systempath

I am trying to setup gitolite using 
the ["directly on the server method" in the docs](http://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite/blob/master/doc/0-INSTALL.mkd#root_method_directly_on_the_server_manually_with_root_access)

Went through the entire setup, uploading the ssh public key etc...
so now I can 
ssh git@myserver 
without prompting me for any passwords, all good.

I reached this step that I need to perform on my workstation, in my case a Mac OS

```
on the client, run cd; git clone git@server:gitolite-admin
```

running that is throwing this error:

```
Initialized empty Git repository in /Users/myLocalUser/gitolite-admin/.git/
bash: git-upload-pack: command not found
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

which tells me that it cannot find git-upload-pack, so I thought I would just have to add its path to the "git" user ".profile"

I just double checked and the path is there!
if I:

```
ssh git@myServer
```

then call:

```
which git-upload-pack
```

I get the path as expected:

```
/usr/local/bin/git-upload-pack
```

What am I missing here?!

I can't seem to clone gitolite-admin, because of it keeps complaining about not being able t find git-upload-pack!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Finally I got this solved by adding the PATH to .bashrc instead of .profile

git user is set to use /usr/bin/bash shell

I haven't realized that when I ssh to my server with user git:

```
ssh git@myServer
```

the PATH variable is being read from .profile in git's home directory.

```
echo $PATH
```

was displaying all the right paths included in .profile

but..

from my wrokstation, when I tried

```
ssh git@myServer \echo $PATH
```

the output was completely different, and the paths were all missing.

After adding .bashrc file to git's home directory, and defined all PATHs I needed inside .bashrc, and added /usr/local/bin/ where git-upload-pack is sitting, it worked as expected.

Always make sure the paths have been set where they *should* have been by running this command:

```
ssh git@myServer \echo $PATH
```

Comment: A quick note: If your remote shell is not bash but zsh, use `.zshenv` instead of `.bashrc`

Answer (score 1):

When you log in to a machine with ssh it starts a "login shell" and some of your login scripts are executed.  If you remote execute a command with ssh, some *other* login scripts are executed.  You can read about this [here](http://www.faqs.org/docs/bashman/bashref_63.html#SEC63).

Your problem is (as you figured out) that the path to git-upload-pack is not set for the "non-login" shell.

You can either change the login scripts as you suggested.  A perhaps simpler alternative is to *specify the path to `git-upload-pack` on the command line* like this:

```
git clone --upload-pack /usr/local/bin/git-upload-pack git@server:gitolite-admin
```

If you have a remote repository for which you have to use the --upload-pack a lot, you can make life easier by configuring git after the clone to always use that path for that repository

```
git configure remote.<name-of-repo>.uploadpack /usr/local/bin/git-upload-pack
```

Unless you named your remote repository, the `<name-of-repo>` is usually `origin`