# Can't clone gitolite-admin

Tags: mac-osx, git, gitolite

I'm trying to setup gitolite on my server which is a mac mini running os X leopard (non-server version).  I believe I correctly installed gitolite using the root installation method detailed on https://github.com/sitaramc/gitolite/blob/pu/doc/1-INSTALL.mkd#_important_points_to_note . The only big difference is that my git user's home directory is set to an external drive connected to the mac mini, in my case /Volumes/Drobo/git .  I'm getting stuck on the part where I try to clone gitolite-admin into my local machine's user directory (running os x lion).

I receive this error:

```
Cloning into gitolite-admin...
Can't exec "git": No such file or directory at /usr/local/bin/gl-auth-command line 192.
fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
```

I have tried the things suggested at [gitolite unable to exec git](https://serverfault.com/questions/226960/gitolite-unable-to-exec-git) but they have not panned out.

running `ssh git@serverAddress info`

returns

```
hello latca, the gitolite version here is v2.0.3-28-g7c8c5a8
the gitolite config gives you the following access:
     R   W  gitolite-admin
    @R_ @W_ testing
```

Also suggested in the thread I've added .bashrc file into the git user's home directory on the server with a single line `export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH` and that has not worked either

line 192 from gl-auth-command is `exec("git", "shell", "-c", "$verb $repo") unless $verb eq 'git-init';`

I'm still a commandline neophyte so please let me know what other information you guys need to help diagnose the problems.

Much Thanks in Advance

Answer (score 4):

### Gitolite 2.x

If *git* is not in the default PATH, then you can set `$GIT_PATH` in your gitolite user’s `~/.gitolite.rc`.

The default `.gitolite.rc` comes with this line:

```
$GIT_PATH="";
```

If your Git installation is under `/usr/local` (so that you have `/usr/local/bin/git`), then replace the above line with this one:

```
$GIT_PATH="/usr/local/bin";
```

See [“support for git installed outside default PATH”](http://sitaramc.github.com/gitolite/g2/tnconv_.html#tips_notes_support_for_git_installed_outside_default_PATH_) in the Gitolite documentation.

### Gitolite 3.x

The 3.x version of Gitolite is a [complete rewrite](http://sitaramc.github.com/gitolite/g3why.html). One of the incompatibilities with respect to the 2.x series is the lack of `$GIT_PATH`. From the “incompatible features”, “high impact” section of the [migration documentation](http://sitaramc.github.com/gitolite/g2migr.html):

> - GIT_PATH **dropped**, **requires presetting**.
>
>   If you need its functionality, add these lines to the end of the rc file:
>
>   ```
>   $ENV{PATH}="...whatever you want...";
>   1;
>   ```

So, for Gitolite 3.x, the `~/.gitolite.rc` change should be something like this:

```
$ENV{PATH}="/usr/local/bin:$ENV{PATH}";
```

(somewhere **before** the final `1;` line)

Comment: You save me. After I upgrading git to newest version and then I encounter this problem. I solved by modifying the $GIT_PATH inside ~/.gitolite.rc. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1):

`.bashrc` is only invoked for interactive shells. Try adding `export PATH=/usr/local/bin:$PATH` to `~/.bash_profile`.

Comment: I tried adding it to the user directory of both my local machine and the remote one and receive the same error.  Is a restart of either required for any of the changes to kick in?